# Regex that matches only the first occurence of a price pattern in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have multiple strings about different products of which some contain only the price of the acutal product but some also extra costs. My problem here is that I only want to extract the price of the actual product out of the string and not any additional costs. The actual price always appears as the first price in the string which is why I tried to solve it with a lazy operator that stops after the first occurence of a specific pattern. However this does not seem to solve my issue.

Example Strings:

2-TB SSD, black, 200.- EUR + Extra Costs. Tel. 1234/12345678 oder Tel. 1234/12345678

PC, white case, 320.- price + 62.- delivery + 95.- setup

PC, black case, 320.- price + 62.- delivery + 95.- setup

2-TB SSD, white, 200.- EUR, Tel. 1234/12345678 oder Tel. 1234/12345678

My current regex: `\d+(?=(\.-)).*?`

I basically want to return the digits right before the first occurrence of (.-) in the string. This is done in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capture group:

```
^.*?\b(\d+)\.-
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` match as least as possible chars
- `\b` a word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+)` capture 1+ digits in **group 1**
- `\.-` match a dot and a hyphen

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aOwU00/1)

A version in Java using a lookbehind assertion with a finite quantifier:

```
(?<=^(?:(?!\b\d+\.-).){0,1000}?)\b\d+(?=\.-)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1dhIDY/1)

With the doubled backslashes in Java:

```
String regex = "(?<=^(?:(?!\\b\\d+\\.-).){0,1000}?)\\b\\d+(?=\\.-)";
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a capture group? Your solution works but I need the pattern to match only the price value without seperating the string into groups.

Comment: Is \K somehow replaceable for use in Java? I already looked it up and only found solutions that are using capture groups.

Comment: @lucas `\K` is not supported in Java. I have added a Java version.